# What is the relationship between momentum method for gradient descent defined in machine learning and the momentum defined in physics

Tags: optimization, gradient-descent

The momentum method for gradient descent in machine learning is defined as

$$
\begin{array}{l}
\mathbf{v}_{t} \leftarrow \beta \mathbf{v}_{t-1}+\mathbf{g}_{t-1} \\
\mathbf{x}_{t} \leftarrow \mathbf{x}_{t-1}-\eta_{t} \mathbf{v}_{t}
\end{array}
$$
where $\mathbf{g}$ is the gradient.

While the momentum in physics is defined as:

$$
p=mv
$$
where $m$ is the mass and $v$ is the velocity.

I don't see how the above two equations are mathematically connected. Does the term **momentum** have a totally different meaning in machine learning from it does in physics?

Answer (score 0):

The physics concept which optimization "momentum" maps best to is drag. For example, if $\beta = 1$, then there is no damping, and you get something very close to the classic laws of motion ($x_t = x_{t-1} + v\cdot dt, v_t = v_{t-1} + \frac{F}{m} \cdot dt$). On the other hand, if $\beta = 0$, it's as if there's a drag force $F'$ acting in the opposite direction of $v_t$, just strong enough to "cancel out" the previous velocity, so that $v_t = (v_{t-1} - \frac{F'}{m} dt) 
 + \frac{F}{m} dt = \frac{F}{m} dt $. Since $F' \propto v_{t-1}$, it seems appropriate to call this drag, since drag does scale linearly with velocity in many cases.